# How to condense a full journal paper to a two-page conference abstract?

Tags: publications, conference, writing

I am in the field of biomedical engineering and have some results for a full paper, trying to submit as a two-page abstract. I figured I could reuse the text I prepared from the full paper, but not sure how to organize the two pager. Would the following plan work?

Abstract - A very brief summary of the question, the methods and main results.
Introduction - Not a full literature review, but only enough to point out the gap for the question I am trying to answer.
Results - I try to briefly summarize the methods in the results section, and highlight the qualitative findings.
Conclusions - I would skip the Discussion section, and put the take-home message here.

I'd probably put one figure to help the readers, if there is a good one.

What do you think of this plan?

PS: I was intending to present a "finding" paper, not a "methods" paper that developed a new technique. In that case, I cannot skip the methods section for sure.

Answer (score 9):

The usual advice for this type of question is:

> Do not shorten, but **rewrite**.

This will not only produce a smoother text, but also will be quicker. Squeezing eight pages to two is a tremendous headache and time consuming. Usually it also results in an awkward text. Writing two pages for something that you understand thoroughly is quicker. Make a good plan what you want to tell in two pages and write the two pages from scratch.

**Edit:** I just saw, that this advice is the same as the most upvoted comment for [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/how-to-reduce-a-papers-size-for-a-page-limited-conference?rq=1). In essence, this question is a duplicate…